# Second order nonlinear differential equations using MATLAB

Tags: math, matlab, differential-equations

I'm trying to input a second order differential equation to solve into matlab over x = 0 to x =1. I can't figure out how. Here's the equation:

y'' = 1 + 0.1 \sqrt{1+(y')^2}

with initial conditions at zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally you solve higher-order equations by converting to a system of first order equations. Here, you would define:

```
y' = v
v' = 1 + 0.1 \sqrt{1 + v^2}
```

Define a function computing the right-hand side, and use `ode45`.

Note that this equation is solvable without much trouble in closed form, too, so should be a good test for how to do it.